# How can a struct inherit from a class in type parameters constrains?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, type-parameter

I saw the following line of code:

```
class Sample<T,U> where T:class where U: struct, T
```

In the case above, parameter `U` is *value type*, and it derives from *reference type* `T`.

How can that line be legal?
Also, if a value type inherits from a reference type,  where is memory allocated: heap or  stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to another answer, there are types beyond T=System.Object where this compiles:

```
class Samplewhere T:class where U:struct, T
```

The "T : class" constraint doesn't actually mean that T has to be a class. It means T has to be a reference type. That includes interfaces, and structs can implement interfaces. So, for example, T=IConvertible, U=System.Int32 works perfectly well.

I can't imagine this is a particularly common or useful constraint, but it's not *quite* as counterintuitive as it seems at first sight.

As to the more general point: as Obiwan Kenobi says, it all depends on your point of view. The CLI spec has quite a complicated explanation of this, where "derives from" and "inherits from" don't mean quite the same thing, IIRC. But no, you can't specify the base type of a value type - it's always either `System.ValueType` or `System.Enum` (which derives from `System.ValueType`) and that's picked on the basis of whether you're declaring a `struct` or an `enum`. It's somewhat confusing that both of these are, themselves, reference types...

Comment: Excellent point, sir. Clearly I hadn't thought it all the way out when I answered.

Comment: I can imagine situations where it would be useful to constrain a type parameter to be a value type which implements some mutating interface.  It's generally evil for structs to implement mutating interfaces because the system can't distinguish mutating members from non-mutating members, and doesn't provide any means by which a struct declaration can prohibit implicit transformations like boxing (which would mean that one couldn't cast to an interface, but would be able to use it as a constraint).  On the other hand, despite the restrictions on their use, ...

Comment: ...mutating interfaces could provide semantics which would otherwise be difficult to achieve (one could probably achieve the same effect as value-type semantics given a cloning method, if one has either a cloning method and uses it every time one copies an object reference, or else has a method which, given two object instances, will mutate one to hold the same data as the other, but when value-type semantics are needed, using value types would probably be more efficient).

Comment: One question sir, Can/Shall I be able to derive a class from struct in c# ?  I think it's possible in c++.  I tried in C# but i had some issues may be I dont know how to do that ?

Comment: @Dhananjay: No, you can't. You can't derive anything from a struct in C#.

Answer (score 2):

All structs derive from the ValueType type implicitly. You cannot specify an explicit base type.
Refer to [this MSDN tutorial on structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(VS.71).aspx) as posted by `codemelt`.

- When you instantiate a struct e.g. as a local variable, they are allocated on the stack (better performance)
- Classes may contain structs as members - in which case they are allocated on the heap.

Comment: Please keep in mind that allocating a struct on the stack does not necessarily imply better performance. It's only in certain circumstances that you'll get better performance using a struct and they exist solely for those circumstances.

Comment: Allocating a large object on the stack will necessitate many copies as the struct is passed from method to method. If your struct is particularly heavy, you may end up with *worse* performance.

Comment: @Sasha: It certainly answers the first question!

Answer (score 1):

MSDN says,

> There is no inheritance for structs as
>   there is for classes. A struct cannot
>   inherit from another struct or class,
>   and it cannot be the base of a class.
>   Structs, however, inherit from the
>   base class object. A struct can
>   implement interfaces, and it does that
>   exactly as classes do.

Comment: just thought the source shall be of help to the OP - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Well, it doesn't answer my question with, more info in the edit#1

Answer (score 1):

> **Sasha Wrote:**
>
> If there is no inheritance allowed,
>   then why is the following legal:
>
> class Samplewhere T:class where
>   U:struct, T
>
> In the case above, parameter U is
>   value type, and it derives from T --
>   reference type

Although that's legal from a generic contract standpoint, you'll never get any useful code that uses that class to compile, because you'll never have a type other than T=System.Object that fulfills the U constraint. You might consider that a very minor bug in the implementation of generics in C#.

Comment: Because Sample<object, double> is legal. Sample<object, anyvaluetype> is legal but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Structs cannot inherit from anything other than System.ValueType or System.Enum.  There is no way a struct can inherit from a normal reference type.  So unfortunately this question cannot be answered.

Comment: <pedant> Or System.Enum </pedant>

Comment: @jon, oh yes, forgot about that one.  Thanks!